# PYTHON EXCEL COMBINE WORKSHEETS

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Have an excel file consisting of multiple worksheets and each worksheet has one column named "Close" and under the "Close" column I have multiple numbers and data. Now using Python I want to combine all multiple worksheet in to one worksheet with side by side column of close and worksheet title as the header for each column? How can I do that?

the concat mehtod in pandas is just putting everything in one column without giving the name of the excel worksheet as title. CODING AS BELOW

```
df_combined = pd.DataFrame()
ex_file = pd.ExcelFile('123.xlsx')
result = pd.concat([df_combined], axis=1)
df_combined.to_excel(writer2, index=False, header=False)
```

[image] AND [image]

RESULT I WANT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make `pd.concat` fully works, you need to concat all dataframe in one. Either by having a list of all dataframe and then call concat, either by looping iteratively. I advice to read one worksheet at a time.

Second solution :

```py
df_combined = pd.DataFrame() 
file = ""

for worksheet_name in worksheet_names : # assuming worksheet_names is a list of all your worsheets
   ws_dataframe = pandas.read_excel(file, sheet_name=worksheet_name)
   df_combined = pd.concat([df_combined, ws_dataframe], axis=1)

df_combined.to_excel(writer2, index=False, header=False)
```

Before exporting your dataframe df_combined, you can change the columns to include the name of your worksheet, in some kind of multiindex columns. For instance :

```py
df_combined.colums = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([worksheet_names, ['Close']], names=['Worksheetname', 'col'])
```

Comment: Great! it worked with iteration method and slight edits.. Thanks alot :)